# Store InputField value in variable - UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am creating a new game all by myself. But I have a problem. I have an InputField and I need its value... I've seen many answers, but inputFieldName.text doesn't work, and I am using UI, declared the InputFIeld and it still doesn't work!
HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the value object on game screen for use DragAndDrop into the script to define public property.
Then you must select text component on awake or start event in script.

```
 public GameObject gameTextObject; // Set this object on gameScreen for use DragAndDrop

        void Start(){

          if( gameTextObject == null)
            {
              // if you set gameTextObject  on gameScreen this object not be null 
              gameTextObject = GameObject.Find("InputObjectName");
            }

         // GetObjectText
         string gObjectTextValue = gameTextObject.Text;

          // SetObjectText
          gameTextObject.GetCOmponent<Text>().text = "Any Text";       
        }
```